# Area between undefined curves

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $R$ be the region enclosed by the $x$-axis and $g(x)$. If the area of region enclosed by $f(x)=x^{2}-x$ and $g(x)=ax-x^{2}$ is $9$, calculate the area of $R$.

I've found that the $x$-intercept of $f(x)$ is $x=0$ and $x=1$ and the $x$-intercept of $g(x)$ is $x=0$ and $x=a$. I've also found that the intercept of between two curves is $x=\frac{a+1}{2}$.

I don't know where I can put those intercepts because the $a$ is not known.

How is the integral would be?

Comment: Do you know how you can calculate the area between to curves?

Comment: You would use equation involving $a$ to represent $F(x)-G(x)$ where $F(x)=\int_0^{a+1\over2}f(x)$ then solve for $a$.

Comment: @Eric S. Yes, I know. When these $x$ values are found, I will divide into some pieces of the enclosed region, then use formula top-bottom. If you just give me the final integral equation is okay to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The area of the region enclosed by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is 9* is translated into mathematics as:
$$\int_0^{\frac{a+1}{2}}{\bigg(g(x)-f(x)\bigg)dx}=9$$
If you solve this for $a$, you can find the area of $R$ as
$$\int_0^a{g(x)dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Distinguish between the cases $a<1$ and $a\geq1$. In both cases express the area between the curves as a function of $a$ and put it equal to 9, then solve for the unknown $a.$